# Magento 2 - cart page custom UI component foreach binding

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, magento2.3.3, data-bind

I want to add a custom UI component template on the cart page. The data is in JSON format and wants to bind forach to display a list of data.

data like as

```
{'name':'5% discount','description':'5% off on purchase','coupon':'WINTEROFF5'},{'name':'15% off','description':'15% off auto-generated coupons','coupon':'WINTEROFF15'}
```

following error as I got

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach:
>   function(){return { data:getCouponList(),as:'coupon'} }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a custom module name "Compnay_MyModule"

**Step 1)** app/code/Compnay/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">                          
            <arguments>                           
                 <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">                                                
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                        
                                   <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/js/view/cart/myitems</item>                        
                                      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                 </item>
                             </item>
                       </item> 
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>        
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 2)** /app/code/Compnay/MyModule/view/frontend/web/js/view/cart/myitems.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'ko

'
    ], function($,Component, ko) {


        var itemList = ko.observableArray();   
        return Component.extend({   
             defaults: {
                template: 'Company_MyModule/myList'
             },
             title:'My Items List',      
             itemList:itemList,          
             initialize: function(){
                 this._super(); 
                 this.populateMyItems();             
                 return this;
             },
             populateMyItems: function(){
                 var self =  this;               
                 this.itemList([
                     {'name':'5% discount','description':'5% off on purchase','coupon':'WINTEROFF5'},
                     {'name':'15% off','description':'15% off auto-generated coupons','coupon':'WINTEROFF15'}
                 ]);            
             }       
        });

    });
```

**Step 3)** /app/code/Compnay/MyModule/view/frontend/web/template/myList.html

```
<h2 data-bind="text: title"></h2>
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>        
      </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemList">
      <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: $index"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
          <td data-bind="text: $data.description"></td>
      </tr>             
  </tbody>
</table>
```

== Demo ====

[image]

Comment: Thank you. it helped me a lot.

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check template (html) and your component (js)
Post your html bind here will be easier for know what exactly problem

The common case foreach in ko html

> coupon.html

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: getCouponList(), as: 'coupon' } -->
    <span class="coupon-name" data-bind="text: coupon.name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

in your component (js) should have function `getCouponList`

Comment: tried this but not working

Comment: post/update your snippet where you binding will be helpful for other can help you